# JS object custom variables

Tags: javascript, dom, object, prototyping

I read somewhere that objects were basically hash tables, and you could assign values to them willy nilly. Well, I am hoping to take advantage of this, but I want to know if it is even possible, if it is considered "correct", and, if there are any unwanted situations.

My situation:

I have a serious of objects (the kind which CANNOT be stored in the DOM!) which I want to assign to DOM objects. My plan is to:

FInd a dom object (A div, or area of some form), and then assign that to the variable myVar

I will then call: myVar.customVal = value
customVal of course is not defined in the DOM specification. Will that even work, though? Will it show up in the DOM, or stay a virtual variable? Is there any way to assign custom values to members of the DOM for access later?

Comment: You can store whatever you want in DOM node/element objects, but it's considered poor practice - nothing says the Javascript spec can't be modified at some point and make your custom properties reserved words and use them for some completely different purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Marc B, the info was very helpful! I'd like to do this with *good* practice -- Is there a better way to associate data to a DOM object?

Comment: I don't know about jquery, but mootools has something called "element storage" that lets you store per-node data, but in a way that won't conflict with any future language/dom changes.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the info! I'd accept your answer if it weren't a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('sidebar');
foo.party = 3;
console.dir(foo);
```

But no, it's not considered good practice. Rather, consider using [HTML5's custom data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/), or better yet, [jQuery's abstraction of them](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: Hey, the jQuery data abstraction is EXACTLY what I need! Thanks for the answer! :)